# SQL Server : select only one row based on a field when there are several rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns: `Name`, `Surname`, `Email`. Data in those columns is not unique.

I need to get result that matches following criteria:

- Select all three columns
- Email records should be unique
- There should be only one record per Email

That means `SELECT DISTINCT` isn't applicable because it could retrieve multiple email records.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can try with `GROUP BY Email, Name, Surname`

Comment: SQL likes to have *you* supply a rule rather than it have to guess at what you want it to do - so even if you "don't care", you generally have to give a rule for how to select 1 row from among many - so, should it e.g. pick the row with the `Name` and `Surname` values that sort earliest, or latest, or use some other column as the criteria?

Comment: Agreed w/ the above. There should probably be a sequence or effdt field indicating the order in which different names became associated with an email address. That way you can select the latest name associated with the email, or earliest, or whatever based on what you actually want, as opposed to just picking a random name out of the hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but most systems support "Windowed Aggregate Functions":

```
with cte as
 ( select Email, Name, Surname,
      row_number() over (partition by Email order by Name) as rn
   from tab
 )
select Email, Name, Surname
from tab
where rn = 1
```

This assigns a ranking to each email and returns only the first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show all unique names associated with each email with one row per email you can use string aggregation.

If using MySQL (you didn't specify the database):

```
select group_concat(distinct name order by name separator ', ') as names,
       group_concat(distinct surename order by name separator ', ') as surenames,
       email
  from tbl
 group by email
```

If using PostgreSQL, string_agg is the equivalent. If using Oracle, listagg.

If you just arbitrarily want any name associated with the email, and you don't care which name, just as long as it's only one, you can use the previous answers.

However if your database doesn't support the with clause or window functions (ie. MySQL), you can use the below to arbitrarily show only one name and surname per email:

```
select x.*, y.surname
  from (select email, max(name) as name from tbl group by email) x
  join tbl y
    on x.name = y.name
   and x.email = y.email
```

This will show the correct surname for the given name because it picks the max(name) first and then gets the surname for that name and email.

Comment: (you didn't specify the database)
Looks like some smart ashoole edited my post. I originally speciefied that it is MS SQL related question.
Thanks anyway.